# How to test connection to an Exchange Server?

Tags: c#, email, exchange-server

I am developing a C# project for sending emails, using the Exchange API.

So far I am perfectly able to send emails, I would just like to know how to test my connection to the Exchange Server.

I need to have a method called TestConnection, that when called tests the connection to the exchange server. Is this possible?

I can't find anything on the Exchange API that would make this possible.. Below you'll find part of the code that I am using to connect and send an email.

```
ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService();
if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(DomainName))
    service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(FromEmail,Password);
service.Credentials = new WebCredentials(FromEmail, Password, DomainName);
service.AutodiscoverUrl(FromEmail, RedirectionUrlValidationCallback);

//Email Setup
EmailMessage emailMessage = new EmailMessage(service);

//EmailMessageSetting:

emailMessage.Save();
emailMessage.SendAndSaveCopy();
```

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 2):

After some digging, I realized that the service.AutodiscoverUrl throws an exception if something is wrong with the connection parameters.

If you entered a wrong domain name, email or password the AutodiscoverUrl will throw an error.

What I did inside my TestConnection method was calling AutodiscoverUrl. This method will set the ExchangeService.Url property with the Exchange Web Services Url, for the email used as parameter, if everything is ok and throw an exception if something is wrong with the email, password or domain name.

In the end if the Service.url isn't null or empty the connection test was successful.

Ps:
Although the AutodiscoverUrl only uses email as a parameter it also validates the password that is in Service.Credentials.

Comment: probably late to a party but in my application I test connection (url and credentials) by simply binding to Inbox folder. every mailbox has one so it is enough to validate whether all data are good or not. and it doesn't create "dummy" objects on Exchange so test doesn't change mailbox state. just my 2 cents.